Eclipse Target showing 'Missing Constraint' errors even when 'missing' bundles present
My target definition contains org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty but is apparently missing some contraints.
The Target Platform State view shows the following information:

As I understand it, the bundle requires jetty.server in any version between 9.4.0 and 10.0.0. It seems to me that there are 2 bundles which match that constraint.
I had tried to switch and reload the target definition but this hasn't helped. I tried to clear .p2 (by renaming the folder) but then my eclipse wouldn't start.
Why does equinox.http.jetty not see those bundles even though they are there?

Note that those are package imports, not bundle versions. Possibly the jetty server plugins don't export those packages, or at a different version, or restrict use of the the packages.

The bundle org.eclipse.jetty.server 9.4.37 exports the package org.eclipse.jetty.server in the same version as the bundle: Export-Package: org.eclipse.jetty.server;uses:="...";version="9.4.37". uses - A comma-separated list of package names that are used by the exported package. ... If this exported package is chosen as an export, then the resolver must ensure that importers of this package wire to the same versions of the package in this list. Maybe this constraint is not fulfilled in your case.
